# Compare 2 select values and alert if they match

Tags: jquery, select

My code is like this, I need this to compare together, not one by one

```
 if ((!$("first-select").val() == 'one') && (!$("second-select").val() == 'two')){
    alert("got it!");                

}
```

but this doesn't work,

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence): `!` has higher precedence than `==`

Answer (score 0):

To condition a different value use `A != B` instead of `!( A == B )`

```
if( $("first-select").val() != 'one' && $("second-select").val() != 'two' ){
    alert("got it!");
}
```

Also in your code you are doing this

```
if( ( !$("element").val() ) )
```

Notice that **!** in **!$("element").val()** is what is causing the error
So if you want to keep the way you do it, it should be like this

```
if ( !($("first-select").val() == 'one') && !($("second-select").val() == 'two') )
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're showing us pseudocode, selectors such as

```
$("first-select").val()
```

would match a custom html element in the form `<first-select></first-select>` If you want to address their ids, then it should be

```
$("#first-select").val()
```

Now, if you wanted to check if one element's value is different than 'one', you should do:

```
if ($("#first-select").val() !== 'one') {...}
```

And not

```
if(!$('#first-select').val() == 'one') {...}
```

See, the second one casts the left side expression to a boolean. (true if the selected option is unset or an empty string, as in  `!''`, and false otherwise as in `!'truthy'`). Therefore, you might be testing something like

```
 if(false == 'one' && true == 'two') { ... }
```

Which will never happen. So let's say you mean to do:

```
 if(value1 != 'one' && value2 != 'two') {
  // I guess they're equal...
 }
```

But you said you wanted to check if the selected values matched on both the elements. Equality won't happen except in a very particular scenario (e.g. there are only two options in each selector and one of each is present in the other), so you probably meant to do:

```
if(value1 === 'one' && value2 === 'one') {
  // I'm sure they're equal
}
```

> I need this to compare together, not one by one

Of course, you don't need to know the option set. Just compare against each other:

```
if(value1 === value2) {
  // I'm sure they're equal
}
```

```js
$('.select_pair').on('change', () => {

  $('#result')
    .removeClass('matching')
    .text('Not matching');

  let select1value = $('#select1').val(),
    select2value = $('#select2').val();

  if (select1value === select2value) {
    $('#result')
      .addClass('matching')
      .text('Matching!!!');
  }
});
```

```css
.matching {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.select_pair {
  margin: 0 0 0 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <label id="result">Not matching</label>
  <select name="select" id="select1" class="select_pair">
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select2" id="select2" class="select_pair">
    <option value="value1" selected>Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
  </select>

</fieldset>
```